# Rotate Icon around another Icon

Tags: javascript, react-native

There is no transform-origin property in react-native so how can I do it ?
I think I should use transformX & transformY props.

```js
  const Marker = () => {
    const rotate = new Animated.Value(???);
    const transformX = new Animated.Value(???);
    const transformY = new Animated.Value(???);

    const doRotation = (newDegValue) => {
      // ?????
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Animated.View transform={[{ rotate }, { transformX }, { transformY }]}>
          <ArrowIcon width={30} height={30}>
        </Animated.View>
        {/* I need to rotate my ArrowIcon around this BaseIcon */}
        <BaseIcon width={100} height={100} /> 
      <View/>
    )
  }
```

[image: need behaviour like this]

[image]

Comment: For me, it is not really clear what exactly you want to have. Could you please explain your expected behavior a little bit more? Thank you

Comment: @Tim I want to rotate <ArrowIcon /> around <BaseIcon /> like on picture. It's necessary to show current vehicle direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

In this example, I am using the [Animated Library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated). First, we are defining a `Animated Value` in the constructor. Then we are creating a `triggerAnimation` function, where we will animate this new value over time using the [timing](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#timing) function.

In the render function, we are defining a new style object called animatedStyle. This style object will handle the rotation of the arrow.  We are using the `interpolate` function to incrementally rotate the arrow. As `inputRange` we are allowing -1 to +1. -1 means a rotation of -360° and +1 a rotation of 360°-, as you can see in the `outputRange`.The interpolate function will automatically handle the mapping between input and output range.

In the return statement we are passing the animatedStyle to our `<Animated.View>`.

Now we can call the `triggerAnimation` function. As parameter we have to pass the desired rotation value.

**Some Examples:**
`this.triggerAnimation(0.5)` would result in a rotation of +180°.

`this.triggerAnimation(-0.5)` would result in a rotation of -180°.

`this.triggerAnimation(0.25)` would result in a rotation of +90°.

`this.triggerAnimation(0.75)` would result in a rotation of +270°.

### Code

**Constructor and triggerAnimation function:**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      currentRotation: 0, 
      value: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }

  triggerAnimation(newValue){
    Animated.timing(this.state.value, {
      toValue: newValue,
      duration: 500,
    }).start(() => {
      // set rotated again
      this.setState({currentRotation: newValue})
    });
  }
```

**render function:**

```
render() {
const animatedStyle={
  transform: [
    {
      rotateZ: this.state.value.interpolate({ 
      inputRange: [-1,1],
      outputRange: ['-360deg', `360deg`],
      }),
    },
  ],
};
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', width: 150, height: 150}}>
    <Animated.View style={[{justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-start'}, StyleSheet.absoluteFill,animatedStyle]} >
      <Icon name={"location-arrow"} size={30} style={{transform: [ {rotateZ: '-45deg' }]}}/>
    </Animated.View>
    <View style={{width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 35, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}/>
  </View>

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.triggerAnimation(0.5)} >
      <Text> 180° Trigger Animation </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
     ...
  </View>
);
}
```

### Working Demo

https://snack.expo.io/B1UzO79Cr

Comment: + 1000 points to you. Thank you so much for your involvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
transform: [{ rotate: '40deg' }] in styles

Example: => https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/mad-cookie

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state=({
      angle:0
    })

  }

  rotate(){
    this.setState({
      angle: this.state.angle + 5
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.rotate()}} style={{position: "absolute", top:20, width:'100%'}}>
          <Text style={{marginTop:20, position:'absolute', top:20}}>Click on me to rotate</Text>    
        </TouchableOpacity >
        <Image style={{height:40, width:40}} source={require('./bus.png')} />
        <View onPress={()=>{this.rotate()}} style={{position: "absolute"}}>
          <Image style={{height:150, width:150, transform: [{ rotate: (this.state.angle+'deg') }]}} source={require('./ss.png')} />    
        </View >


      </View>
    );
  }
}
```